# Blogger page menu overriding my code

Tags: html, css, blogger, menubar

Trying to put together a justified page menu in Blogger, can build it just fine when below posts, but when under header, it reverts back to template page menu style. Is there some code I need to disable?

*My design*

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">ONE</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">TWO</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">THREE</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">FOUR</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
  display: table;
  height: 64px;
  width: 100%;
}

#nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  width: 16.666666667%;  /* (100 / numItems)% */
  line-height: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 24px raleway
}​

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #nav li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I only put together code and understand bits and pieces. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change id nav to any other name then change the css reference too. Check the following, I changed it to mynav:

```
<ul id="mynav">
  <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">ONE</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">TWO</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">THREE</a></li>
  <li><a href="x">FOUR</a></li>
</ul>

#mynav {
  display: table;
  height: 64px;
  width: 100%;
}

#mynav li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  width: 16.666666667%;  /* (100 / numItems)% */
  line-height: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font: 24px raleway
}​

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #mynav li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this - it doesn't work, and I have no idea why as I've even taken out the default code for the navbar widget.